# How to get datatype of column in spark dataframe dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe - converted dtypes to map.

```
val dfTypesMap:Map[String,String]] = df.dtypes.toMap
```

Output:

```
(PRODUCT_ID,StringType)
(PRODUCT_ID_BSTP_MAP,MapType(StringType,IntegerType,false))
(PRODUCT_ID_CAT_MAP,MapType(StringType,StringType,true))
(PRODUCT_ID_FETR_MAP_END_FR,ArrayType(StringType,true))
```

When I use type [String] hardcoding in `row.getAS[String]`, there is no compilation error.

```
df.foreach(row => {
  val prdValue = row.getAs[String]("PRODUCT_ID")
})
```

I want to iterate above map `dfTypesMap` and get corresponding value type. Is there any way to convert dt column types to general types like below?

```
StringType --> String
MapType(StringType,IntegerType,false) ---> Map[String,Int]
MapType(StringType,StringType,true) ---> Map[String,String]
ArrayType(StringType,true) ---> List[String]
```

Comment: Convert it to a dataset when you first create it. That'll make all this stuff easier.

Comment: Thanks philantrovert . I never used Datasets. Can you please provide sample example here?.

Comment: if it is Dataset, don't we need to use row.getAs[String]("PRODUCT_ID")?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Datasets make it easier to work with types.
Dataset is basically a collection of strongly-typed JVM objects.

You can map your data to case classes like so

```
case class Foo(PRODUCT_ID: String, PRODUCT_NAME: String)
val ds: Dataset[Foo] = df.as[Foo]
```

Then you can safely operate on your typed objects. In your case you could do

```
ds.foreach(foo => {
  val prdValue = foo.PRODUCT_ID
})
```

For more on Datasets, check out
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets